# Download a file with certain extension from ftp using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to download a file with extension `.tar` from `ftp`. The tar file has the following name: `archive_432r2332234343432424342342.tar`
I am using the following code:

`$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient`
`$WebClient.DownloadFile("http://ftpname/archive*.tar","C:\archive.tar")`

I get the error: `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Read much more about the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol and also the documentation of [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell). A `GET` [request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message) should give the *precise* URL, without any `*` (so without [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))). Also, backslashes *perhaps* need to be escaped (but I never used PowerShell or Windows, so I could be wrong)

So you could need

```
  $WebClient.DownloadFile("http://ftpname/archive_432r2332234343432424342342.tar",
                         "C:\\archive.tar")
```

How do you find the *precise* URL? On *some* web servers (e.g. a suitably configured [lighttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/)), you *might* do a `GET http://ftpname/` request and obtain some [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) page that your program could later parse. This is a matter of convention and configuration of the web server.

So obviously you need more than one HTTP requests. Probably two. The first one would query the web server for a list of resources; you could get some HTML5 content as a reply (with many URLs inside it). Your program would parse that HTML5 content and make a *second* HTTP request for the actual URL.

Be of course aware that [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) and HTTP are *different* protocols. You need to understand what [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)s are.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It doesn't work with backslashes escaped. I can not download the file with full name (archive_432r2332234343432424342342.tar) because 432r2332234343432424342342 is changing after a while.

Comment: As I explain, you first need to take a few days to read about the HTTP protocols and about URLs and about FTP and HTML5 and later you need to fix your code. You cannot reasonably code a program for the Web without understanding Web related technologies. You could play with [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) to experiment with HTTP